# disable Postfix TLS support for specific destination server

Tags: postfix, tls

I am trying to configure postfix to disable TLS for a specific remote smtp server that serves for multiple recipient domains.

I have set up a policy map that already contains some entries for specific recipient domains that work fine. But ist there a way to configure postfix to disable TLS for a remote smtp server regardless of what domains are hosted there?

I have tried quite a few entries in my TLS policy map file but without any success. I tried:

- smtp.server.com           none
- [smtp.server.com]         none
- smtp.server.com:25        none
- [smtp.server.com]:25      none
- 12.23.34.45               none
- [12.23.34.45]             none
- 12.23.34.45:25            none
- [12.23.34.45]:25          none

btw: yes, I postmapped the modified policy file :)

Still postfix tries to relay to that host using a TLS connection. As soon as I configure a specific recipient domain delivered via this mx, things work fine and no TLS connection is established. But since there are hundreds of recipient domains on the remote host, I cannot configure all of them in my policy :)

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

As documented in http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls_policy, a hostname or IP enclosed in square brackets is not resolved to an MX; it is assumed to *be* the MX.

Please provide postmap -q output for this map, and log entries that show what goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking about. I entered the hostnames and IP-addresses of the remote MX in my tls policy file, enclosed in sqare brackets, with and without trailing port number.

Comment: postmap -q [mx.server.net] <tls_policy_file> returns "none" as it is configured in the policy.

But anyway postfix logs say (partial, not enough characters :): 
setting up TLS connection to mx.server.net[12.23.34.45]:25
Trusted TLS connection established to mx.server.net[12.23.34.45]:25: TLSv1 (...)
status=deferred (lost connection with mx.server.net[12.23.34.45] while performing the HELO handshake)

When I set up a tls policy for the recipient domain (that is served on that host), then no TLS connection is established.

Comment: WHat happens when you use the IP literal ?